# How convert '1305' char to the time format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a time in char format.
The values is:
[image]

And I need to get all visit in some range. Like from 8:50 till 9:20.

What is the best way to do it? There are 24 format of values.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 has a `time` datatype. As you aren't using fractional sections `time(0)` would do for you. With a storage space of 3 bytes this is more compact than storing as a string and also ensures you can't get invalid times such as `10:67`

Comment: I use data base where they already have these fields. So I can`t change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String comparison should work fine until you cross a day boundary.

To fall in a particular interval, a visit should start before the end of that interval, and end after it starts:

```
where    from_time < '0920'
         and to_time > '0850'
```